# JS execute in order with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

How can I control the JS executes in order with ajax? Here is my code:

```
function forexample() {
  $(".bewait").css("display", "block");
  ajaxrequest();  // here is a ajax request method. 
                  // I also added "async: false" in the method.
  $(".bewait").css("display", "none");
}
```

when I run the `forexample()`, it works correctly in Firefox, but I found the chrome did not, it seems chrome runs the ajax method firstly, then runs the css control js together.

How can I fix it to run correctly in chrome?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `$(".bewait").css("display", "none");` to the onComplete handler. For example:

```
$(".bewait").css("display", "block");

$.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : url,
            async : false,
            data : postData,
            complete : function (){
                $(".bewait").css("display", "none");
            }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback to ensure the second css statement only executes after a response is recieved:

```
ajaxrequest({
    onResponse : function() {
        $(".bewait").css("display", "none");
    }
})
```

You'll probably want to handle errors as well but this should be enough to get started